# How to batch print files in Notepad++?

Tags: printing, notepad++

I want to print a set of files in one go in Notepad++.

I tried searching on Google, but to no avail.

Is there a built-in feature or some other way that would allow me to batch print files from Notepad++?

Comment: Try selecting all of them in Windows Explorer, right click and select print. If you are on Windows that is...

Comment: @TheUser1024 Nope, doesn't work. No option for print, and I seriously think it needs to be from inside Notepad++.

Comment: Okay, once the files are associated with Notepad++ the option is gone. I checked for .txt files that were still associated with regular Notepad, then you have a right click print option. It also works for PDFs and such, so the option comes fromt he program, you are correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer. There's a Notepad++ plugin called `Print all`. Just go to `Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager`, then click on `Available`, then go down to `Print all`, check it, and install it. Works like a charm.

Comment: This plugin doesn't offer a print settings window, so you cant print all in landscape. As soon as you hit start, it batch prints everything you have open in portrait.

Comment: @TheC4Fox You can - you just have to configure your default printing settings to landscape (sorry for the late reply, hope you have fixed whatever problem you had before now)